# How to plot data to evaluate for appropriate kernel?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am talking about SVM but this can be useful for other algorithms.

I would like to plot the data so I can see the pattern and therefore be in a position to decide if a linear classifier or RBF would be best.
If they are not linear it would be good to do a 3d plot then maybe.

Let's use the 20newsgroups that is available in the scikit-learn library thus making the example reproducible.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

categories = ['alt.atheism', 'comp.graphics', 'rec.motorcycles']
newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=categories, remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'))
newsgroups_test = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='test', categories=categories, remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'))

y_train = newsgroups_train.target
y_test = newsgroups_test.target

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(newsgroups_train.data)
X_test = vectorizer.transform(newsgroups_test.data)
```

How do I do the proper checks though plotting?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is actually not about programming, and it is based on a very shallow (and completely wrong) understanding of the relevant context.

Comment: Checking two of those features would be a good start in the suggestion towards getting an idea about the data visually. The code I provided is more like if we have that dataset how do we proceed to check how the data are positioned?

Comment: Checking a random sample of 2 features among tens or hundreds would *not* be a good start of any use. The answer to your question is that simply we *don't* proceed to check how the data are "positioned".

Comment: ok. Then how do you suggest to decide if a linear kernel should be used?

Comment: This is a huge subject, a completely different question, and again not about programming. You are very welcome to ask at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Not to be misunderstood, there is a whole (sub)field called exploratory data analysis (EDA), which is often the very first stage of an ML project - but, as said, it's a whole field on its own... So, an actual answer to your question could be *please familiarize yourself with EDA*...